# jquery get value by variable name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a variable with jsonData in my page:

```
JSON_Values=[
    {"ID":"1","Name":"MyName1","Selector":"S1"},
    {"ID":"2","Name":"MyName2","Selector":"S2"}
]
```

The name `JSON_Values` can change so I have receive a variable that holds the name of the `JSON_Values`:

```
function useJSONData(nameOfVariable, filter) {
    //How to access the Data inside of JSON_Values here???
    //Value of nameOfVariable is correctly set to JSON_VALUES
    var myJSONData = $(nameOfVariable);
    jq.grep(myJSONData, function (n, i) {
        return n.Selector === filter
    });
}
```

Can someone provide me any help?

Comment: `JSON_Values.filter(x=>x.Selector === filter)`

Comment: I only have the name of the variable not the JSON_Values itself in the method

Comment: Is this what you're after? var myJSONData = this[nameOfVariable];

Comment: The solution was window[nameOfVariable]. Many, many thanks!

Comment: Damn, I was too late... ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `nameOfVariable` is in global scope (which you should avoid), you can use

```
window[nameOfVariable]
```

or if in object scope:

```
this[nameOfVariable]
```

Comment: The name of the variable is generated of the ClientID of the control it belongs to and the column name. So I should be unique, don't know how to avoid global scope :(

Answer (score 0):

You can accessing the json data like so: `var id = myJSONData[0]["ID"]`

You can loop through if you need to do something for each item.

Here's a little example: Hope its helpful.

```js
function useJSONData(nameOfVariable, filter) {
    //How to access the Data inside of JSON_Values here???
    //Value of nameOfVariable is correctly set to JSON_VALUES
    var myJSONData = $(nameOfVariable);
    $.each( myJSONData, function( index, value ){
     var id = myJSONData[index]["ID"]
     var name = myJSONData[index]["Name"]
     var selector = myJSONData[index]["Selector"]
   var result = "<p>" + id + " | " + name + " | " + selector + "</p> <br>"
      
      $("#output").append(result);
      //value("<p>" + id + " | " + name + " | " + selector + "</p> <br />");
    });
}

JSON_Values=[
    {"ID":"1","Name":"MyName1","Selector":"S1"},
    {"ID":"2","Name":"MyName2","Selector":"S2"}
]

useJSONData(JSON_Values);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="output"></div>
```